# Is there a way to have FullCalendar start at closest date in listYear view?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have FullCalendar up and running on my site with the events being pulled from google calendars.  It all works great, except when I switch to the yearList view.  Yes it shows all of the events properly, but I was wondering if there is a way to have it focus on the closest event to the current date

i.e. it's July and when you switch to listYear view it starts at January.

I don't want to disable past events or anything like that.

So I guess the question is: Can you get the closest event to the current date, and have the list scrollTop to that event?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

in action:

www.pvband.org/schedule/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,listYear'
        },

        displayEventTime: true, 

        displayEventEnd: true,


        //removed google api key and cal events for this snipet

        eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.url) {


                var fancyContent = ('<div><div class="eventDetailsHeader">Event Details</div> <div class="eventDetails"> <label><b>Event: </b></label>' + event.title + '<br>' + '<label><b>Date: </b></label>' + event.start.format('ddd, MMM DD, YYYY') + '<br>' + '<label><b>Start Time: </b></label>' + event.start.format('h:mm a') + '<br>' + '<label><b>End Time: </b></label>' + event.end.format('h:mm a') + '<br>' + '<label><b>Location: </b></label>' + event.location +  '<br>' + '</div></div>');

                $.fancybox.open({
                    src : fancyContent,
                    type : 'html',





                })
                return false;
            }
        },


        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you make a snippet on here which demonstrates the issue? Unless you've changed https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/ to something else, it should switch to the current date as far as I understand. The only other time it wouldn't is if you've already navigated to another date in the view you were previously in.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, I added a link and the current snippet I'm using.